# need help with QR factorization proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I under this proof for QR factorization and I also know how to find Q and R. However, I got stuck with the notation of the proof. I understand everything before the yellow highlighted line, then I don't understand the part talks about 
"We may assume that $r_{kk} ≥0$, if $r_{kk} < 0 $, multiply both $r_{kk}$ and $ u_{k}$ by $-1$ )

I understand R is a upper triangular matrix with its diagonal all positive. But I just don't understand the notation here. also, is
 $r_{k}$ a vector or a matrix in that matrix notation down there Please help me out.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $Q = [u_1, \cdots, u_n]$ is a basis, any vector from that space can be written as a sum of those $u_i $ multiplied by some coefficients. If the column space is smaller than the whole vector space, i.e. has smaller dimension, then you only need $k $ vectors $u_i, k < n $ to write all vectors from the column space.

Thus if $x_k $ is a vector from the column space, it can be written as a sum of the vectors of the basis $Q$. But since the column space has dimension $< n $, we only need some $k $ vectors:

$x_k = r_{1k}u_1 + \cdots + r_{kk}u_k + 0\cdot u_{k+1} \cdots + 0\cdot u_n $

Where the last coefficients are $0$ because we do not need those last vectors.

Then they say that $r_{kk} $ can be assumed to be positive. Because if it is not, we do:

$r_{kk}u_k = (-1)r_{kk}(-1)u_k = (-r_{kk})(-u_k) $

And $(-r_{kk})$ is positive.

Also because of how matrix multiplication works,

$x_k = Qr_k $

And collecting all $r_k $ in a matrix $R $ we get $A = QR $.

Answer (score 0):

Notations in **fat** are vectors, notations in CAPITAL are matrices, other are reals. If it says $R=[\mathbf{r}_1\ldots\mathbf{r}_n]$ it means that the matrix $R$ is represented by its column vectors $\mathbf{r}_k$. Gram-Schmidt procedure gives that the coefficient $r_{kk}\ne 0$ (the vector $\mathbf{u}_k$ must be linearly independent on the previous). Since the sign of the vector $\mathbf{u}_k$ is not important, they suggest to pick the coefficient positive changing if necessary the sign of $\mathbf{u}_k$.